# WPF Using the StoryBoard How do I reset styles every click

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I just created a custom control with a storyboard animation.

And the eventtrigger that starts the animation looks like this

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                            To="#00C8FC" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
```

As you can see, on the `MouseDown` event I am changing the color of a border, *that's it.*

How ever after clicking it and it changes color, let's say I click another control.
In that case I want to set the most recent border's background to White.
At the moment it's changing the border color of every instance of the control I have on the form.

I need to be able to reset the colors using XAML somehow every click so.
Picture this..
I click a button, the border goes blue.
I click another button (same type) and that one gets blue and button one resets to white.

At the moment it's like
I click a button, it turns blue.
I click another one and it turns blue too but the old one stays blue.

This is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: You want to keep it until another Button is clicked, or only as long as the mouse button is pressed on each Button?

Comment: I want it to be blue until I click another button

Comment: Then your approach is wrong. You should instead use RadioButtons. Create and use a RadioButton Style and Template.

Comment: Ahh! Good thinking

Comment: You may also want to take a look a Visual States. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/radiobutton-styles-and-templates

Comment: I'm actually on there right now, I found that right before asking the question. You've been working with WPF for a long time eh? I've just recently got into Storyboards.

Comment: Almost forgot to add them in a group, scary stuff.

Comment: Looks more like a `ListView` to me. Doesn't really matter much. Anyways, you can implement this behavior using `Triggers` on the `IsSelected` property of a `ListViewItem`

Answer (score 1):

`MouseDown` is not the recommended method to indicate the selection of a `ListViewItem`. The more reliable method is to use the property trigger in a `Style`.

[image]

View the code below, and you'll find that I use the `Trigger` in a `Style` to handle the `ListViewItem` selection status. If you use the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` event, you'll notice that you cannot enumerate all the event that affects the selection.

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>Coll Programmer1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>MinecraftGeek1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Steve</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>John</ListViewItem>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid Name="RootPanel" Background="Transparent" Height="48">
                            <Rectangle Name="SelectedBorder" Width="8" Fill="#00c9fe"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="12 0 0 0" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="SelectedBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="RootPanel" Property="Background" Value="#00c9fe" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

[image]

When you want to keep the animations on, just replace the setter to actions:

```
<ListView>
    <ListViewItem>Coll Programmer1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>MinecraftGeek1</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>Steve</ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem>John</ListViewItem>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Grid Name="RootPanel" Background="Transparent" Height="48">
                            <Rectangle Name="SelectedBorder" Width="8" Fill="#00C8FC"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Opacity="0.0" />
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="12 0 0 0" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                To="1" Duration="0:0:0.25">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.25">
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="RootPanel" Property="Background" Value="#00C8FC" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```